# Stacking in CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dom, browser

I am trying to understand stacking in CSS. From what I read online, following is the stacking order:

1. The background and borders of the elements that form the stacking context
2. Positioned descendants with negative stack levels
3. Block-level descendants in the normal flow
4. Floated descendants
5. Inline-level descendants in the normal flow
6. Positioned descendants with the stack level set as auto or (zero)
7. Positioned descendants with positive stack levels

I tried few experiments and they all seem to confirm this order. But then I started looking at the home page of Github at https://github.com/home and ran into a case which does not seem to align with this. I am seeking an explanation for the same.

On Github's home page, there is a section which says "Accelerate high-quality software development. Our AI-powered platform drives innovation with tools that boost developer velocity.". This section resides within a `div` with classes `home-campaign-productivity js-section overflow-hidden px-3 pb-8 pt-5`. The `div` has `static` position. A sibling of this `div` has the classes `container-xl position-relative` applied to it and it has `relative` positioning with `z-index` set to `auto`. This `div` has an image as a child  which has `absolute` position. This image is the main background image that is visible at the top of the landing page.

Surprisingly, even though this image has `absolute` position, it appears below the text, which has `static` position.

Could some please help and explain this.

Comment: Try to re-create the situation with the smallest code and you will find the culprit. Stacking order is more complex that what you have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the div with class `home-campaign-productivity`, but containing the text, is an h3 element with a transform. This [transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#ref-for-propdef-transform%E2%91%A7)

> ... results in the creation of a stacking context. Implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent stacking context, at **the same stacking order that would be used if it were a positioned element with z-index: 0**. If an element with a transform is positioned, the z-index property applies as described in [CSS2], except that auto is treated as 0 since a new stacking context is always created.

It therefore belongs to Step 6, same as the img element, and since it's later in tree order, it and its descendants paint over the image.